# How to get Rhythmbox sorting asian names correctly

Tags: rhythmbox, japanese

Rhythmbox cannot sort Asian (Japanese in my case) names correctly. Is there a way to make it work?
I cannot post images, so I cannot post evidence :-(

Thanks.

Comment: Use a public image host like **[TinyPic](http://tinypic.com)**, upload your picture there and either edit your post by placing the link or simply comment the link.

Comment: Could you post a couple of the names in the order they are displayed (that are incorrectly sorted).

Comment: Are files with Japanese names sorted correctly in Nautilus?

Comment: I confirmed this problem I can't see any rules, it looks really random on Rhythmbox. It doesn't happen on the Audacious version 3.7. In Nautilus Japanese letters are ignored and the first alphabet letter in the filename applied for the sort order.